# UPDATE variable and OUTPUT TO filepath

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to ask a user to insert a filepath and then output the result to that filepath:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE outputPath AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(50)".

UPDATE outputPath.
OUTPUT TO outputPath.
```

This doesn't seem to be working. But when I do for example:

```
OUTPUT TO "C:\temp\test.txt".
```

It seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the value of a variable in an OUTPUT statement:

```
OUTPUT TO VALUE( outputPath ).
```

VALUE is also used with INPUT FROM, INPUT THROUGH and INPUT-OUTPUT THROUGH.

(A "naked" variable name will be treated as a file name, no quotes needed -- a result of  one of those "makes a good demo" decisions 30 years ago...)